# Unnest a JSON stringified array in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following table in Google BigQuery :

```
+------------+---------+---------+
|    Name    |  City  | items   |
+------------+---------+
| James     | Dallas   |[{'text': 'pear', 'line_total_excl_vat': '24','product_id': 100}]

| John      | Chicago  |[{'text': 'apple', 'line_total_excl_vat': '29','product_id': 200},{'text': 'banana', 'line_total_excl_vat': '34','product_id': 300}]
+------------+---------+
```

I'm trying to achieve something like this :

```
+------------+---------+---------+----------------------+--------------+
|    Name    |  City   | text     |  line_total_excl_vat | product_id
+------------+---------+
| James     | Dallas   |  pear    |       24             |       100

| John      | Chicago  |  apple   |       29             |       200

| John      | Chicago  |  banana  |       34             |       300
+------------+---------+
```

The column "items" is actually a string. Is there a way to unnest this data format and achieve the view that I want in BigQuery ? Thanks !

Comment: Do you know the names of the columns?  If not, you can't do this with a simple `select`.

Comment: Yes I know the name of the columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT Name, City, 
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(json, '$.text') AS text,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(json, '$.line_total_excl_vat') AS line_total_excl_vat,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(json, '$.product_id') AS product_id
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(items,'$')) json
```

If to apply to sample data from your question - as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'James' AS Name, 'Dallas' AS City, "[{'text': 'pear', 'line_total_excl_vat': '24','product_id': 100}]" AS items UNION ALL
  SELECT 'John', 'Chicago', "[{'text': 'apple', 'line_total_excl_vat': '29','product_id': 200},{'text': 'banana', 'line_total_excl_vat': '34','product_id': 300}]"
)
SELECT Name, City, 
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(json, '$.text') AS text,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(json, '$.line_total_excl_vat') AS line_total_excl_vat,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(json, '$.product_id') AS product_id
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(items,'$')) json
```

output is

```
Row Name    City    text    line_total_excl_vat product_id   
1   James   Dallas  pear    24                  100  
2   John    Chicago apple   29                  200  
3   John    Chicago banana  34                  300
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of fiddleing with json_extract and json_extract_array in combination with unnest() ...

```sql
WITH t AS (
  SELECT 'James' as Name, 'Dallas' AS City, "[{'text': 'pear', 'line_total_excl_vat': '24','product_id': 100}]" AS items
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'John', 'Chicago', "[{'text': 'apple', 'line_total_excl_vat': '29','product_id': 200},{'text': 'banana', 'line_total_excl_vat': '34','product_id': 300}]"
)

SELECT 
  # we'll unnest this array in the next statement and grab its elements
  JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(items,'$') as arr
  
  # unnest() turns array into table format - jason-function extracts fields from each row
  ,ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT
  
      JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(i,'$.text') as text,
      JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(i,'$.line_total_excl_vat') as line_total_excl_vat,
      JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(i,'$.product_id') as product_id
   
   FROM UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(items,'$')) as i 
   ) AS unnested_items
   ,* # original fields for reference
FROM t
```

This creates a nested output that you can use later on (see the JSON representation of the output, it's more clear) - if you want to flatten the table you can lateral join this resulting array ...

```sql
WITH t AS (
#     Name    |  City  | items   |
  SELECT 'James' as Name, 'Dallas' AS City, "[{'text': 'pear', 'line_total_excl_vat': '24','product_id': 100}]" AS items
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'John', 'Chicago', "[{'text': 'apple', 'line_total_excl_vat': '29','product_id': 200},{'text': 'banana', 'line_total_excl_vat': '34','product_id': 300}]"
)

SELECT 
   * 
FROM t CROSS JOIN UNNEST(ARRAY((SELECT AS STRUCT
  
      JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(i,'$.text') as text,
      JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(i,'$.line_total_excl_vat') as line_total_excl_vat,
      JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(i,'$.product_id') as product_id
   
   FROM UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(items,'$')) as i 
   )))
```