# Question about JSON Stringified values in BigQuery. I have been trying to UNNEST this stringified data but it keeps showing null

Tags: sql, json, google-bigquery

ok so i have a column of this data :

```
{"PaynetInstantTransfer":
  {
  "id": {"value": "02c8e435-c890"}  
  "userIp": {"value": "000.000.000.000"},
  "purpose": "TRANSFER",
  "cardType": "NOT_AVAILABLE"
  }
}
```

but the data type for this column is STRING. It was stored in a column named RECORD.
I cant use the standard "test.test" RECORD sql to unnest it.

I tried to use the JSON Stringified from https://www.holistics.io/blog/how-to-extract-nested-or-array-json-in-bigquery/#handling-stringified-json-in-bigquery but it shows no data or null.

This is my code :

```
select 
  id,
  json_extract_array(h, '$.purpose') as purpose
FROM `table.table`
left join unnest(json_extract_array(request)) as h
where date(created_at) = "2023-08-31"
and id = 100475508 --just filtering out 1 user because the table is so big
order by created_at desc

limit 2
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXvPN.png)

The data shown in BigQuery is like this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LB9ha.png)

Comment: You can use   `JSON_PARSE(RECORD)` and contain it on some temporary table (for example contain in column name `json_data`), and to extract `purpose` value, you can use `JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(json_data, '$.PaynetInstantTransfer.purpose')`

Comment: And why you use `json_extract_array` on both (on select statement and unnest statement) . You can use `JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR` instead on select statement. This is refererence on SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63100219/unnest-a-json-stringified-array-in-bigquery?rq=2